# Taylor and Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I need to calculate limit of sin(x)*cot(tanx) at 0 using Maclaurin series I took the usual approach but did not get anything of help.

Comment: Wrong site; you will want http://math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: See also [Maclaurin Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html), has a nice nb anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The Taylor formula:

```
taylor[n_] := Sum[D[f[x0], {x0, k}]/k!*(x - x0)^k, {k, 0, n}]
```

your function:

```
f[x_] = Sin[x] Cot[Tan[x]]
```

now you get:

```
t = taylor[2]
(x - x0) (Cos[x0] Cot[Tan[x0]] - Csc[Tan[x0]]^2 Sec[x0] Tan[x0]) + 
 1/2 (x - x0)^2 (-2 Csc[Tan[x0]]^2 Sec[x0] - Cot[Tan[x0]] Sin[x0] + 
    Sin[x0] (2 Cot[Tan[x0]] Csc[Tan[x0]]^2 Sec[x0]^4 - 
       2 Csc[Tan[x0]]^2 Sec[x0]^2 Tan[x0]))
```

and this your problem

```
t /. x0 -> 0
```

> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity
>   encountered. >>

You have to evaluate the limit!

```
s = Limit[t, x0 -> 0]
1 - (5 x^2)/6
```

With Mathematicas `Series`you get:

```
Series[f[x], {x, 0, 2}] // Normal
1 - (5 x^2)/6

Plot[{s, f[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]